# Parsing apache files grep awk

Tags: parsing, awk, sed

I'm trying to do a simple script task but I have a very serious lack of knowledge in AWK and I'm not able to understand exactly how to accomplish this silly task.

Basically I have a very big regular vhost.conf with hundreds of domains.

The idea is just iterate or parse this unique file and get a list of ServerName and DocumentRoot.

The file is divided in multiple  parts. If I run this command I get an output like:

```
grep -E "DocumentRoot|ServerName" /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-pro.conf | awk '!/#/{print $2}'
/home/webs/t2m/PRO/default
t2m.net
/home/webs/uoc/PRO/default
uoc.com
```

so...now. How process this output? If I was able to concatenate the path and the domain name into just single one line, maybe I could store in a array or in a file and then just take the info piece by piece. But I simply don't know how to do it.

Any clue or tip about how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post sample Input and expected sample output in code tags, could help you on same.

Comment: add a sample of input file... add expected output for clarity.. if you simply need to join every two lines, use `pr -2ats' '`

Comment: you can also use `xargs -l2`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
awk '/<VirtualHost/ { sn=""; dr="" }
     /ServerName/ { sn=$2 }
     /DocumentRoot/ { dr = $2 }
     /\/VirtualHost/ { print dr, sn }' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-pro.conf
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe is very rude for me to ask you how to parse if for example, a Alias have multiple strings?. I'm trying with your command but I'm able only to get the first string in ServerAlias : /

Comment: Well, I was able to do it with a inside loop for :( I don't know if this ok or not but I will post here:     awk '/<VirtualHost/ { sn=""; dr="" } /ServerAlias/ { sn=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){sn=sn" "$i }}  /DocumentRoot/ { dr = $2 } /\/VirtualHost/ { print dr, sn }' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-pro.conf

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate your comments. I will pr command as well. I'm going to share how I did it. I was luck to find some kind of awk magic. To be honest, it worked but I don't what I'm doing and this is bad for me :P

I had this output:

```
/home/webs/t2m/PRO/default
t2m.net
/home/webs/uoc/PRO/default
uoc.com
```

So what I did to turn it into just one line was:

```
grep -E "DocumentRoot|ServerName" /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost-pro.conf | awk '{key=$2;getline;print key " " $2}'
```

this way my new output is something like:

```
/home/webs/t2m/PRO/default t2m.net
/home/webs/uoc/PRO/default uoc.com
```

then I think I will store this into a temp file to iterate after and store it to a var.

Thanks!